# Word for "the capacity of habituating to new environment"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, vocabulary

I am in search of a word that has the meaning of 'capacity of a person to habituate to a new environment'.

I can use adaptability. Like he is more adaptable than others. But 'adaptable' may not necessarily imply to a place, it may imply adapting emotions also.

So is there any word that signifies the capability of a person who habituates to a new environment quickly. f I call it X. I can say as. He is Xer than others.

Comment: I would think "He is more adaptable than others" describes what you mean quite clearly. It doesn't necessarily imply adaptation to a new place, but depending on the context this could be clearly implied. Sometimes the word "flexible" is used in this sense too: "He is more flexible than others."

Comment: @Damon - But to me, "flexible" is even more related to emotional habituation than "adaptable."

Comment: Yeah, we can use adaptable, flexible in any sense, but when the context is fixed to an environment. Is there any word? It should be applicable to his capacity of adapting to new environment only.

Comment: 'Environment' itself is often metaphorically broadened. And adaptability will be to the conditions obtaining at a new location.

Comment: "Relocatable" is a word that sounds good to me.  But I couldn't locate a definition to justify it for your situation after a quick search.

Comment: Maybe **compatible** or **matchable**.

Answer (score 2):

> **[Acclimatization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acclimatization)** (UK also acclimatisation; US also acclimation) is the process in which an individual organism adjusts to a gradual change in its environment (such as a change in temperature, humidity, photoperiod, or pH), allowing it to maintain performance across a range of environmental conditions. –Wiki

E.g., he *acclimates* better than others.

**acclimate**, verb, ac·cli·mate \ˈa-klə-ˌmāt; ə-ˈklī-mət, -ˌmāt\ –[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acclimating)

> : to adjust or adapt to a new climate, place, or situation

Adjective:  **acclimatizable**

E.g., he is more *acclimatizable* than others.

I implore you to reword and use the verb or noun forms. I've never heard the word *acclimatizable* spoken out loud.

Comment: It's very rare, but I might suggest *acclimable* as less of a mouthful than *acclimatizable* - though my spellchecker likes neither.

Answer (score 2):

In a military context you would use the word **deployable**. For example see this article "The Rapid Deployable Corps: Commanding NATO troops on missions wherever necessary" at http://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/topics_50088.htm

Another example sentence is "Army Rangers are rapidly deployable troops trained for mountain, desert and swamp terrain and often go after special operations targets." found [here](http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/08/18/us-usa-military-women-idUSKCN0QN03I20150818).

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no such word in English -- at least not that I could think of; so I propose a multi-word solution:

> He adapts to new environments more easily than most.

Comment: OP specifically says that he is looking for a hyponym of 'adaptable' referring solely to 'place'.

Answer (score 0):

To become **integrated** or **melded with** in a new environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of terms referring to adaptability of a plant (or person or tissue) to a new place. They will require an adjective, so it's not a single word.

[Transplant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/transplant?s=t)

> to remove (a plant) from one place and plant it in another. (Def 1)
>
> to bring (a family, colony, etc.) from one country, region, etc., to another for settlement; relocate. (Def 4)

One could say, "His family *transplanted well* to Washington, D.C."

[Graft](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/graft)

> Horticulture. a bud, shoot, or scion of a plant inserted in a groove, slit, or the like in a stem or stock of another plant in which it continues to grow. (Def 1a)
>
> Surgery. a portion of living tissue surgically transplanted from one part of an individual to another, or from one individual to another, for its adhesion and growth. (Def 2).

One could say, "He *grafted quicker* to Japan than his younger peers."

Answer (score -1):

The word *Adaptable* fits your requirements.

From The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com.ezproxy.denverlibrary.org/view/Entry/2112):

> adaptable, adj.
>
> > 2. Able to adjust to new conditions or situations, or to changes in one's environment.

Comment: Hello Jacob. OP specifically says that he is looking for a hyponym of 'adaptable' referring solely to 'place'.